# R Select all Nth list Items from a list of list

Tags: r

Suppose having a list of list made by this code :

```
Lst<-list(list(c(1,2,3),c('A','B','C')),
            list(c(4,5,6),c('D','E','F')))


>Lst
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 4 5 6


[[3]]
[1] "D" "E" "F"
```

How to extract all the seconds elements of all sub-lists (Lst[[1]][2] and Lst[[2]][2])to get this output :

```
> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sapply` over `Lst`

```
c(sapply(Lst, `[[`, 2))
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

---

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
flatten_chr(map(Lst, 2))
```

Comment: I think `map` also allows you to just use an integer - `flatten_chr(map(Lst, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pluck` with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(Lst, pluck, 2) %>% 
         unlist
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```